# Is it possible to use two .babelrc files?

Tags: gulp, babeljs, rollup

I have a project that runs both a build using rollup and a build using browserify for two different outputs. Now, they are both located in the same root dir and I have separate gulp-tasks running for both of them.
My problem is that my browserify task wants a .babelrc file with the following configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

and my rollup task wants this configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015-rollup"]
}
```

My question is, can I have two separate .babelrc files and configure which one to use in my gulp and karma config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a lot before asking this question and right after I posted I found a possible solution:

```
gulp.task('rollup', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/server/index.js', { read: false })
    .pipe(rollup({
      plugins: [babel({
        presets: ["es2015-rollup"],
        babelrc: false
      })]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```

By configuring one of the tasks to **not** use the babelrc I could of course configure it myself directly. This isn't a great answer and I would've preferred to just added the name of a babelrc file.